# Azure Functions-like solution with ability to run Win32 desktop application

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cloud-services, azure-batch

I'm trying to move some computations to Azure cloud services. One of the steps of the workflow I'm trying to implement includes running a Win32 desktop application generating a file. Obviously, we cannot have a user interaction for cloud calculations, so the application is launched with command line arguments. The process starts, generates a file, and then exists. At the moment I cannot refactor the code and move this functionality to command-line windowless utility.

First, I chose Azure Functions because they are intended for event-driven short calculations, and that's exactly what I need. Also they are cheap. But I encountered a problem that processes in Azure Functions are being executed inside a [sandbox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox) blocking User32/GDI32 system calls and thus preventing me from launching desktop applications.

Another solution I came up with is mounting a virtual machine drive with all needed Visual C++ redistributables installed and then using Azure Batch with nodes based on the pre-configured drive. But this solution has another drawbacks, since it takes minutes to mount a new node. Of course, I could have some nodes that are always active, but anyway the further scaling is slow and having active nodes is not so cheap. Also I have a feeling that Azure Batch is a bit overkill, because there is no need for HPC in my case. Azure Functions' computation capabilities are enough for me.

Is there some kind of compromise solution? So that I would have a solution with fast scaling and quick responses, but with no need to establish Azure Batch based on Azure Virtual Machines?

Answer (score 1):

A lot of GDI32 calls are available now but in a containerized form.

So, you can deploy a function with the desktop application but inside a docker container.

Refer the following [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/app-service-announces-general-availability-of-windows-container-support/)for more explanation.

Refer the following [documentation](https://www.bing.com/search?q=deploty%20azure%20function%20in%20a%20container&cvid=b81e6744f0c24618bceb1e90cbe6915f&aqs=edge..69i57j0l2j69i64.7880j0j1&pglt=2083&FORM=ANNAB1&PC=U531) on how to deploy containerized function.

Comment: tfti. Do I understand correctly that I should choose a service different from Azure Functions, since according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale "Linux is the only supported operating system for Docker containers"? Also "Windows" options is disabled during the creating of the Function App, if I choose "Docker Container" publish mode.